# Deleting files in external storage - hard delete possible?

Tags: android, file-io, android-external-storage

When I delete files that are stored in external storage e.g. photos

Is there a way to delete the file using a 'hard' delete such that it cannot be recovered easily?

i.e. if other apps have access to external storage, I don't want them recovering photos that were deleted already

Comment: Just something which popped in my head - what about moving the file to internal storage and deleting it there? 

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary apps without root access already have no means to recover deleted files. Once `unlink` is invoked, the file is gone, period.

Apps with root access can potentially recover an unlinked file by directly reading raw virtual device files (`/dev/storage/*`). Both removing a file and moving it to different directory merely removes directory entry without touching file contents (they are simply marked as "unused" if file is no longer referenced anywhere). Thus it is possible to gather residual sectors, that previously belonged to file and haven't been overwritten since removal. Preventing this can be varying degree of hard depending on specific filesystem. The external filesystem on most external storage is vFAT. In vFAT it is possible to prevent residual sectors by opening the file before removing and overwriting it's full length with zeroes. Other filesystems (most notably, Samsung's F2FS) might take measures, that make securely removing files a lot harder due to wear-leveling built directly into the filesystem itself.

Do not bother with defending against circuit-level wear-leveling. It happens on such low level, that recovering the data is infeasible without butchering the phone and using a tunneling microscope. Only flash controller firmware can see that data, and most controllers do not allow access to the flash firmware from OS programs.

---

Of course, you still have to ensure, that the file haven't been cached in some secondary storage facility (for example, the thumbnail of image may have gotten cached in thumbnail cache, or in system MediaProvider). And of course, some other program might have copied the file to somewhere prior to the removal. Therefore, the safest way to assure "secure removal" is encrypting the files: even if someone steals them prior to removal or restores their contents after removal, without a decryption key those contents are useless. Byte-by-byte overwrite comes second.

Some people might suggest a tough brute-force approach: after unlinking a file, create a throwaway temporary file and fill it with amount of random data equal to free space remaining on partition. That will efficiently defeat all forms of wear-leveling and prevent file recovery in *most* cases. Unfortunately, this method is very slow, extremely taxing on flash memory and does not defend against apps, that previously copied the file.

- <sup>"unlinking" is a term, traditionally used to describe removal a file in Linux (google for "inodes"). Removing a file with `File#delete` does unlink it</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are worried about data protection from recovery, you should complete next steps:

1. open a file for writing
2. write a random sequence of data instead of real data in this file
3. delete that file.

Comment: This will have limited effect on flash storage (SSD, mobile phones, etc.), as the cells that you are writing to are not necessarily the cells that you are reading from, due to wear leveling.

Comment: Oh, I'm begging you. If this is sensitive data, then these side effects can be neglected.

Comment: What side effects? @CommonsWare is pointing out that the protection from recovery that you are working towards might not actually be working...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I meant that this decision increases the wear of the SD card. Of course,  CommonsWare is right, some cells may not be available for writing, but in general, the file will already be very difficult to recover.
Special software, as I know it, this way protects against data recovery, the difference in the number of recording cycles. And I do not claim the absolute correctness of the decision I proposed.